# How to Block outgoing calls and Text SMS

Tags: android

I am developing an App in which I need to block the teenager from
using mobile while driving, I need to block the call and
sms. please help . any small hints and clues will do. please help me!

Comment: Is there any way to do this? (http://textecution.com/) how thy can able to do this? Plz suggest me the hint.

Comment: it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586

Comment: @Thiru they had done nothing but set there app as car home app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/DetectCalls/src/com/varma/samples/detectcalls/receivers/OutgoingCallReceiver.java

Comment: Thanks. It will help. But is there any way for block Text message?

Comment: check 'Dharmendra' answer it will help to end call on Outgoing call

Comment: for SMS : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android don't do any thing in sendSMS method.

Comment: i want to access the default text message app programmatic .

Comment: Any way to block outgoing sms for default app? @Thiru

Answer (score 11):

This code will block your **all call (INCOMING AND OUTGOING)**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import com.CallLogApp.helper.BlockNumberHelper;
import com.CallLogApp.util.UDF;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context;
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String outGoingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, outGoingNumber);

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                endCallIfBlocked(outGoingNumber);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

     }

     private void endCallIfBlocked(String outGoingNumber) {
        try {
            // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
            // ITelephony getter
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  

            if (new BlockNumberHelper(context).isBlocked(outGoingNumber))
            {
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` state will call each time when your call going to connect and when you received incoming call**

There is no any method that you can know weather it is incoming call or outgoing call

But you can end call which is going to connect in both scenario

Comment: @Dharmendra import com.CallLogApp.helper.BlockNumberHelper;
import com.CallLogApp.util.UDF; not reolved

Comment: @user406090 these are custom function to check whether the phone number is added in block list or not. you can use your logic to check the block number.

Answer (score 0):

To block outgoing calls, you need to register a `PhoneStateListener` like:

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(new MyListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Then define your `MyListener` class like:

```
private class Test extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);


        switch(state)
        {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK://this case is for outgoing call 
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING://this case is for incoming call
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the answer by Dharmendra saying that:

> There is no any method that you can know whether it is incoming call
>   or outgoing call

In fact, there is.

To distinguish incoming calls from outgoing calls, you have to listen to `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` as well.
Now:

when you see first `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and then `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, it's an outgoing call;

when you first see `CALL_STATE_RINGING` and then `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, it's an incoming call.

At second, you could either use a `PhoneStateListener` or listen to `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`. From what I could see, first the intent gets received by the `BroadcastReceiver`, then the `PhoneStateListener` gets notified.

```
final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
theFilter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
mService.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, theFilter);

class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```