# how to block a out going call?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am blocking the incoming call by using following code,

```
{
     telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
     telephonyService.silenceRinger();
     telephonyService.endCall();
}
```

But I want to know how to block the out going call ?

Comment: Suggestion. Look for fixed dialing settings.

Comment: @lucifer i need programatically

Comment: ya, so search for the code that activate fixdialing using code

Comment: hi venkat give your mainifest reciever code

Comment: i write like this but it is not working whats wrong with that code?

Comment: why you have given name ITelephony1 instead of ITelephony
are you testing on emulator or device ??

Comment: @vipin emulator i already give ITelephony interface to incoming call so that why i give ITelephony1 to out going call

Comment: venkat i think same will work for both i have got solution of your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and in your broadcastreciever

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener (context);
telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

with this you can get number

see this to block call [How to Block outgoing calls and Text SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595092/how-to-block-outgoing-calls-and-text-sms) check dharmendar answer

Comment: i know how to get the number but i donot know how to block it

Comment: check the link i have give for bloacking the call

Comment: in that only they write code for only find out the outgoing call.. i need how to stop the outgoing call