# How to allow to make call for some contacts only?

Tags: android

i am new to Android Application Development.

I developed on application which represents retrieve the contacts from device and made call any one of those.I install that .apk file in my device,it is working good.

But my requirement is I have to allow for  some contacts only to make call ,means i have to 
control to make call for some contacts.

please help to go forward.

thank you,

bye..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7595480/726863

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to do.But we should make it work by running some logic.Put all the contacts that you don't want make the call into an array. Whenever you are going to make a call just compare with the array,check that number and if that number existing in the array dont forward the number to dialer otherwise forward it to the dialer. I hope this should satisfy your requirement.