# iOS - As I can block incoming calls and messages from any contact from an application?

Tags: ios, telephony

With this done on android:

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html

[How to Block outgoing calls and Text SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595092/how-to-block-outgoing-calls-and-text-sms)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but iOS is not Android, it is not possible to achieve this from an application, due to iOS restrictions.

Comment: and it can be illegally? I mean do and post on Cydia.

Comment: Can't say anything about Cudia, sorry