# Display dialog on activity incoming call

Tags: android, dialog, action

I Have two question:

1. It's possibile to display a dialog over the sceen incoming call (when the phone rings)?
2. It's possibile to know when the phone rings for an incoming call? (Is there an action?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Follow this link:

[Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)

```
It's possible to dispaly a dialog over the screen incoming call
```

When you get the event of the `incoming call` you need to `startactivity()` which you want to display but you need to do it after `a little delay` else the the default screen will override your screen. Once the default screen comes, you should call your screen. The delay will be `between 500 - 1000 ms`, this you need to test at your end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not possibile to display only a popup over the screen of the incoming call ? and...what action should I use to know if the phone rings?

Comment: I have shared a link. It is there. Yes you can show inside an activity with no view.

Comment: @VineetShukla I'm trying to create the activity in a way that the answer buttons will still be visible (not full screen). is it possible? I would appreciate a reference to relevant text if so.
Thank you!

Comment: answer buttons will still be visible ----- do you mean the native screens button? What exactly is your moto behind it?

Comment: I wrote proof of concept application that does exactly it: https://github.com/inez/CustomIncomingCallScreen