# Can we intercept incoming call in android?

Tags: android

How we can intercept incoming call in android?
i have to stop incoming call in default application, any one have any idea please give me direction
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586

Answer (score 0):

You should extend a BroadcastReceiver and then register it.

In code:

```
CallReceiver callReceiver = new CallReceiver();
IntentFilter callFilter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(callReceiver, callFilter);
```

Or register in your manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes We Can Intercept incoming Call by Using Hack Code of Itelyphony Interface.
It simply create an instance of telyphiny service and it has a method to end incoming call.

```
telephonyService.endCall();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```