# How to disconnect incoming call in android by programatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I want to disconnect incoming call for a particular time.

How can i do this is it impossible ?

I searched and i find it is impossible. please help me.

```
public class Telephony3 extends Service 
{
  Context context;  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {

        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        try
        {
            StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
            TelephonyManager telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);  
        }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }  

    class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    //Disconnect the call here...
                    try{
                        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
                        telephony.endCall();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("",e.getMessage());
             }

                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    public void onDestroy()
    {

    }

}
```

---

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
make another package com.android.internal.telephony and make one interface ITelephony

public interface ITelephony 
{
    boolean endCall();

    void answerRingingCall();

    void silenceRinger();

}
```

and when i call this emulator from another the calling is happening. any thing wrong here please suggest me.

thanks in advance

Comment: here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586

Comment: @Vineet Shukla - Does it work on 2.3+?

Comment: permission is needed if you want to disconnect the incoming call.

Comment: @Vineet Shukla - MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is not available on 2.3+.

Comment: yes, i wrote android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE in the manifest file but when i call from another emulator it's not disconnect.I it work for 2.2 or any other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate your own activity that handles action "ACTION_ANSWER".

Register your application component as a intent handler.

Comment: and I found one link that may help you....http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html)  is a blog post which suggest a possible workaround.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);             
  buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
  getContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

from

http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html

Comment: This link doesn't actually tell you how to **disconnect** a call.  Without any explanation, it's hard to get much from this answer.  Please consider adding a little more.