# How to programmatically redirect incoming calls to voice mail when my Calendar has a busy event

Tags: calendar, sms, android-studio

Being new to Android development I have been researching StackOverflow for an answer to this question: How to mute the phone ringer for all incoming messages and calls when I am supposed to be in a Meeting as indicated by my Calendar.
I am able to access the calendar and able to check if present time is within the times set for an event. But how do I send any incoming phone calls to voice mail (and send a text message to caller).
I have gone through lots of questions here:

"[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/detecting-an-incoming-call-coming-to-an-android-device)"

"[Incoming call broadcast receiver not working (Android 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603400/incoming-call-broadcast-receiver-not-working-android-4-1?rq=1)"

"[How to detect incoming call with the help of Broadcast Receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257649/how-to-detect-incoming-call-with-the-help-of-broadcast-receiver?rq=1)"

"[Custom incoming/outgoing call screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401709/custom-incoming-outgoing-call-screen-in-android?rq=1)"

"[how to make an incoming call from our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518613/how-to-make-an-incoming-call-from-our-application?rq=1)"

"[Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phonekiosk-mode-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)"

"[How to disconnect incoming call in android by programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059818/how-to-disconnect-incoming-call-in-android-by-programatically?rq=1)"

The ITelephony using AIDL looked promising untill I found out that it no longer works under Android 4.2 etc due to security issues.

At the moment the answer:
"[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/detecting-an-incoming-call-coming-to-an-android-device)" seems to be better simply because it seems to handle incoming calls in an elegant way - but the answer does not talk about how to (a) Silence the Ringer, (b) End the Call/Divert it etc - the example explains how to determine what state the phone is in at any given time. The other drawback seems to be I am struggling to unregister the listener function which means even after the example app has been terminated, the listener still seems to remain active and jumps into action whenever there is a call. Only way to stop that seems to be to restart the phone - which is very annoying.

The other aspect is that most of these questions are a year or more old and some of the old answers are no longer valid - as I mentioned earlier - the ITelephony looked promising but no longer works with new phones.

The Google documentation seems to suggest that a program can programmatically wrap up an answer to an incoming call in a SMS Text message by sending an Intent etc - but no examples anywhere and looks like the Google's documentation may be out of date (or I am reading an old version of it on the internet - though don't know how it is possible since I am using Google Search to find an answer.)

Comment: None Muhammad Babar, I did not get any response from anyone and I got busy with other things. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No i was also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Silencing the ringer and stopping the incoming / outgoing call is still possible.

First, the example from "[How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)" is the correct way to detect the incoming call.

Now, for silencing the ringer and stopping the call:

First, create an interface named "ITelephony" under the "com.android.internal.telephony" package:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQoVc.png

And add this code to the interface:

```
public interface ITelephony
{
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

Then, on the method where you want to silence the ringer and stop the call, add this code:

```
//TelephonyManager
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get the getITelephony() method
Class c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

// Disable access check
m.setAccessible(true);

// Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
ITelephony telephonyInterface = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephonyManager);

//Invoke silenceRinger
telephonyInterface.silenceRinger();

// Invoke endCall()
telephonyInterface.endCall();
```

Finally, in your manifest, you need to add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

I have tested this code on many devices and it works, if you have any problem, feel free to ask me :)