# How to filter incomming calls (blacklist) - no reflection

Tags: android, blacklist

I was wondering if there is a way that I can filter (block) incoming calls on Android (consider 2.1 and up). I found solutions using reflection, but it seem not to be very clean and reliable solution. Is there any standard or google recommended way to do that?

UPDATE: Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

use the following broadcast receiver to get the incoming phone number and compare it with the numbers that are in your created filter list

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.w("DEBUG", state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = extras
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber, 2000).show();
            Log.w("DEBUG", phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help. You need to create a list of numbers in blacklist by your application's User interface.

Comment: 1) Also use following on manifest file within your application tag.

        <receiver android:name=".BroadCastClassActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


2) and add permission : "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

Comment: Thank you, that is standard way so far. But now I need to block that call if it is on the black list - that's the part when unwanted reflection usually kicks in.

Comment: consider this flow : 1) application does have interface to add the numbers that you need to block   2) store those numbers in a array list    3) once any call is incoming we get the number, right ?    4) then compare that number with those in array list that we had stored earlier   5) if the number that received is in array list, then disconnect the call else proceed the call :)

Comment: Yes, I wonder how to disconnect the call not using reflection.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586

Comment: I know, and thank you for helping me, but linked solution uses reflection.