# How to access the built-in Auto Reject List

Tags: android

Under system settings -> call settings, there is an "Auto Reject List".  This is the same list when the user pulls up a number in the built-in phone app and "Add to blacklist".

How to programmatically access this list?

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You cant, you have to create a listener and a blacklist yourself, take a look here:

[How to filter incomming calls (blacklist) - no reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535666/how-to-filter-incomming-calls-blacklist-no-reflection)

And here:

[Android 4.0 Telephony API with blacklist for phonenumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740858/android-4-0-telephony-api-with-blacklist-for-phonenumber)