# Outgoing Call Android

Tags: android

My application wants to get the event at which the call is ringing on the other side. Or when, the user on the other side has picked up the call. I tried `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` but it is of no use to me. I have gone through the `TelephoneManager`, but i am not able to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to phone state of the device, check this link:

[Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)

Try to achieve with `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` of the `telephoney manager`:

**CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK**

At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

Comment: I have already tried CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. As soon as we call a number CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK state is called immediately i.e before the ringing. I want the event when the call is ringing or the call is picked up by the other person.

Comment: No luck for outgoing call. Outgoincall call cannot receive RINGING state.