# Decline call in android

Tags: android, call, telephonymanager

How to automatically decline the incoming call from app in android after letting the call to ring for 5 secs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**check this link:** [Android: Taking complete control of phone(kiosk mode), is it possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586)

```
 try{

                TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
                telephony.endCall();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("",e.getMessage());
     }
```

Comment: Don't you need to root the phone for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: 
You can Reject Calls Quickly With Root Call Blocker for Android! http://www.xda-developers.com/android/reject-calls-quickly-with-root-call-blocker-for-android/