# Lock Android Device to Run Only One App

Tags: android, locking, kiosk-mode

I was wondering if anyone had a relatively simple solution for us.

We created an app to be used by our clients on android devices that we give them.

We would like the client to only be able to use our app and have limited access to everything else (i.e. settings, email etc.) What is the best way to achieve this without using 3rd party apps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371607/how-to-build-software-limiting-user-action-to-one-single-app-on-android/26372012#26372012

Comment: I saw that answer and that is not what we are looking for. Our app is not a kiosk. We just want to limit them from changing things on the device. Can we delete all apps (including mail, phone, playstore etc) and lock the user from redownloading them?

Comment: My answer got deleted by a moderator (maybe because it was a commercial solution) but it saved us a boat load of time. Check out SureLock. It does what you need and if it's within your price range, it might save you time reinventing the wheel as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may not help but the L preview has a task locking feature included that may be of some insight, I'm not aware of how it functions as yet

Task locking

The L Developer Preview introduces a new task locking API that lets you temporarily restrict users from leaving your app or being interrupted by notifications. This could be used, for example, if you are developing an education app to support high stakes assessment requirements on Android. Once your app activates this mode, users will not be able to see notifications, access other apps, or return to the Home screen, until your app exits the mode.

http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html

Hope this helped

Answer (score 8):

1. Suppress the Title Bar & Make Your App a Launcher
2. Root Your Tablet
3. Modify System Files and Settings to hide the soft keys

On the next link you can find the complete solution for the Nexus 7 (2012)

http://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/

Answer (score -1):

simple Answer is:

1. Lock Install button with modify system settings.
2. Create your own customized-ROM and apply your requirement to that ROM.

more info, visit XDADavelopers