# Block exit on Ionic application ( PhoneGap / Cordova )

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I have an application and I would like to block the exit of it to the people that doesn't know the application, 
how can i do it?
I only found a function to block back button...

Thank you so much...

Comment: Do you mean to disallow the user from exiting the application? Because I highly doubt that such a thing is allowed by any operating system.

Comment: Yes... Because i have a ionic APK used in a kiosk for a client of a store so I would like to block the exit of it... Isn't possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I could find is called **task locking** or **screen pinning** on Android. It is only supported on Android Lollipop (5.0) or higher. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) has the following to say about this feature:

> Android 5.0 introduces a new screen pinning API that lets you
>   temporarily restrict users from leaving your task or being interrupted
>   by notifications. This could be used, for example, if you are
>   developing an education app to support high stakes assessment
>   requirements on Android, or a single-purpose or kiosk application.
>   Once your app activates screen pinning, users cannot see
>   notifications, access other apps, or return to the home screen, until
>   your app exits the mode.

There are some other questions asked regarding task locking, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426654/lock-android-device-to-run-only-one-app) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85013/how-to-enable-task-locking-in-android-5-0-production-devices).

I have been able to find a Cordova plugin for this [here](https://github.com/oddmouse/cordova-plugin-locktask), however it doesn't seem to be very active at this moment in time.

Unfortunately, I don't think that this will actually solve your problem. From what I have been able (or unable) to find, this just doesn't seem to be possible. I think it is similar to closing an app on iOS with code, it is simply not allowed by the developers of the operating system.